Как сделать так чтоб программа увидела исполняемый файл внутри контейнера docker
Возникла проблема , есть dockerfile
FROM python:3.8-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "channel_process_creator.py"]

также есть dockeer-compose.yml для создания контейнера этого образа
  channelizer:
    container_name: channelizer
    image: channelizer
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - redis
    environment:
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      REDIS_CHANNEL: ${REDIS_CHANNEL}
      MONGO_CLIENT: mongodb://mongodb:27017/
      MONGO_DB: work_db
      MONGO_COLLECTION_CHANNELS: channels_collection  
    volumes:
      - ~/drivers/:/app/drivers/

В общем томе drivers есть исполняемый файл ss301 который при обычном запуске  вызываетcя вот так вот
proc = subprocess.Popen(['./drivers/ss301', channel_name])

но при попытке запуска из контейнера, где тоже есть папка drivers в которой есть этот файл с правами доступа на выполнение выдает ошибку
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './drivers/ss301'

может кто подскажет как решить проблему
